# Change Bulma default colours with scss without downloading/installing

Tags: sass, bulma

I am attempting to simply change the colour of the "is-primary" class in [bulma](http://bulma.io/). I am attempting to write a scss file to change the values without installing bulma via npm. I am attempting to import by using the cloudfare link, is this possible?

this is my scss file:

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4./css/bulma.cssbulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables";

$tech-blue : #2c3e50;
$primary : $tech-blue;

@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.3/css/bulma.css";
```

This file compiles but I cannot find the corresponding css file and makes no affect to my actual page.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think that this is possible.** The variables in use by Bulma are only accessible by SCSS. So you need to build the whole thing to have your colors blend in. The rendered CSS already contains:

```
a {
  color: #00d1b2; /* can't change that later on  */
  …
}
```

A feature request for Bulma would be to make those variables accessible via [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). That way you could easily customize the look even with the pre-rendered CSS from the CDN.